# Format double as 4+ digit String

Tags: java, string, double

I have a `double` which contains values such as:

- 19.52
- 5.1
- 6.13
- 101.5

It will not contain more than 2 fractional digits. That is being checked for. If there are more than 2, the rest can be ignored.

I'd like to convert it to a `String` which has 4+ digits, like this:

- "1952"
- "0510"
- "0613"
- "10150"

How can I do that?

I'm using someone's API and the last 2 digits are specified as being always for the first 2 digits of the fractional part, that's why I need to do this.

Comment: `10150` has 5 digits though, and the final 0 is unnecessary.

Comment: @Sweeper the final 0 is necessary to show where the decimal point should be when converted back

Comment: @Gimmethe411 Then you should include that in your question.

Comment: How do you know where the decimal point should be? How should I know whether "1952" means 1.952 or 19.52 or 195.2?

Comment: @Gimmethe411 That is necessary due to the 4 digits rule, as well. Thus, there no indicator that you want to preserve two fractional digits. Also, what should happen if there are more than 2 fractional digits?

Comment: @Sweeper I updated the question. The last 2 digits are always for the fractional part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can multiply your number by 100 to remove the decimal point (because you only have 2 decimal digits), and then use the format `0000` to format it:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0000");
System.out.println(df.format(x * 100));
```

where `x` is your double.

Comment: Nice, now in java instead of C#. ;)